# Razor Pages: How to include pagesection in a partial page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a Razor Pages layout page that includes a nav bar as a partial page

```html
<html>
...
<body>
...
<partial name="_Nav" />
```

Inside my _Nav.cshtml

```html
<div class="links">
    <a href="#link1">link 1</a>
    <a href="#link2">link 2</a>
<!-- custom links that are set by each page  go here-->
</div>
```

This layout is used by every page in the website. I would like to be able include "extra" links that pertain to each page in the website.

I've tried doing it was `@RenderSection`, but it seems that sections are only allowed in the `Layout` page. Does this mean I need to do away with my `_Nav` partial and and lump all the code into one file? Or is there a way to keep an organized code structure and still pass some code around? With jinja2 code blocks this is no problem, so I'm hoping there is a nice way in Razor Pages as well!

Also, I really don't want to pass full html strings from the c# class out to the html, I'm already passing out any variables I need in the links.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since `sections` aren't allowed in partial views, how about if you add your links to the `ViewData` under a specific key on each page where you need to add links then pass it to your partial view which takes a `ViewDataDictionary` as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, its a good idea, I tried, but could not get razor pages to access html as a value for a viewdata key. Do you have an example of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RenderSection` can only be called from a layout page.

**There is no such plugin to add the dynamic link to the partial view.**

As a workaround,you could put a div outside the _Nav.cshtml like below and use `RenderSection` to dynamic add link to the div:

```
....             
    <div class="links">
        <partial name="_Nav" />
        @RenderSection("Html", required: false)
    </div>
....
```

_Nav.cshtml:

```
<a href="#link1">link 1</a>
<a href="#link2">link 2</a>
```

Test View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

//do your stuff...

@section Html
{
    <a href='#link3'>link3</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I was hoping to avoid it, but guess I will take the "razor pages plunge" :) Thanks!

Comment: It seems you want to use the default razor pages plugin to meet your requirement.After a long researching,there is no such plugin to did it.Because what you did is in the partial view,it is different from the razor pages.I think the easier way is to use what i did or what @HMZ did.It is impossible to avoid it.If my answer helped you,could you please accept as answer.It could also help others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to store html in your `ViewDataDictionary`.

On every view that has extra links to add, store a `List<string>`, strings being urls, something like this:

View:

```
@{
   ViewData["Links"] = new List<string>(){ "https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com" };
}
```

Then in your Layout view:

```
<partial name="_Nav" view-data="@ViewData" />
```

Now in your partial view:

```
//Default Links
@if (ViewData["Links"] != null)
{
  //We have extra links
  List<string> links = (List<string>)ViewData["Links"];
  foreach (string link in links)
  {
    <a href="@link">link1</a>
  }
}
```